# Comparing two iterators of a different type in a template function

Tags: c++

No C++11 or Boost :(

I have a function with the following signature.

```
template<class INPUT_ITR, class OUTPUT_ITR>
void DoWork(const INPUT_ITR in_it, const INPUT_ITR in_it_end, OUTPUT_ITR out_it, OUTPUT_ITR out_it_end, CONTEXT_DATA)
```

Normally some complex processing takes place between the input and output.. but sometimes a no-op is required, and the data is simply copied. The function supports in-place operations if the input and output data types are the same. So I have this code.

```
    if (NoOp)
    {
        if (in_it != out_it)
        {
            copy(in_it, in_it_end, out_it);
        }
    }
```

If an in-place operation has been requested (the iterator check), there is no need to copy any data.

This has worked fine until I call the function with iterators to different data types (int32 to int64 for example). Then it complains about the iterator check because they are incompatible types.

```
error C2679: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<unsigned __int64>>>
```

This has left me a bit stumped. Is there an easy way to perform this check if the data types are the same, but simply perform the copy if they are different types?

Thanks

Comment: *How* do you call your `DoWork` function? What is the arguments? What is the *types* of the arguments?

Comment: vector<uint32> to vector<uint64> iterators for example. The result of the operation based on context may increase the size of each data element, in which case user needs to provide bigger output. There will be assert if output size is too small.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the test into a pair of templates; one for matching types, one for non-matching types.

```
template <class T1, class T2>
bool same(T1 const &, T2 const &) {return false;}

template <class T>
bool same(T const & a, T const & b) {return a == b;}
```

Beware that this can give confusing results when used with types that you'd expect to be comparable. In C++11 (or with Boost, or a lot of tedious mucking around with templates) you could extend this to compare different types when possible; but that's beyond what you need here.

Also, note that you're relying on formally undefined behaviour, since iterators over different underlying sequences aren't required to be comparable. There is no way to tell from the iterators themselves whether this is the case.

Comment: A bit risky: `same<double>(0.0, 0.0f)` is false but `same<float>(0.0, 0.0f)` is true. OK in this context though.

Comment: I assumed from the code that `INPUT_ITR` and `OUTPUT_ITR` are iterators, so in your example you are comparing two iterators which could be from different containers.

Comment: I didn't know that is undefined! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a workaround. Any better suggestions welcome.

Overload the function to provide an in-place version. It's up to the user to request in-place now (in-place using the old function will perform the redundant copy in case of no op).

```
template<class ITR>
void DoWork(const ITR it, const ITR it_end, CONTEXT_DATA)
{
    if (! NoOp)
    {
        DoWork(it, it_end, it, it_end, sSourceSpec, sDestSpec);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mike's suggestion will certainly work (define a function that does != if the arguments have the same type and returns false if they have different types). But in many context having explicit in-place and copying variants is a better design.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::iterator_traits` and a custom `is_same` type trait since you don't have c++11:

```
template<class T, class U>
struct is_same
{
   static const bool value = false;
};

template<class T>
struct is_same<T, T>
{
   static const bool value = true;
};

if(!is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<INPUT_ITR>::value_type, 
            typename std::iterator_traits<OUTPUT_ITR>::value_type>::value)
{
    copy(...);
}
```